# Como agregar un número a un arreglo con condición en C

Tags: c

Necesito agregar un elemento a un arreglo siempre y cuando cumpla determinada condición (por ejemplo que sea positivo).
Esto es lo que tengo pero no se como hacer para que se agregue al arreglo.

```
void cargar(int a){
    int ar[11];
    int nu, i;
    for (i=0;i<11;i++){
        printf("ingrese numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&nu);
        if (nu>0)
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que podría ser algo como:

```cpp
    #include <stdio.h>
    
    int main()
    {
        int ar[11];
        int nu, i, j = 0;
        for (i=0;i<11;i++){
            printf("ingrese numero: ");
            scanf("%d",&nu);
            if (nu>0){
                ar[j] = nu;
                j++;
            }
            
        }
        
        printf("\nNumeros agregados:");
        for (i=0;i<j;i++){
            printf("\n%i", ar[i]);
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

https://onlinegdb.com/9STkuRaF0

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no filtra entre numeros positivos (que son los que quiero que se agreguen al array) y los que no. Me agrega todos

Comment: seguro?, a mi me agregó solo los positivos https://tmpsee.com/v/0ydkfgycip

Comment: Sisi estaba bien. Gracias